# What does Torah want to convey from this lineage?

Tags: names, esav

Torah is given by God, Blessed Be He, everything in it was mentioned to mean something and to convey a lesson from it. When we look into Genesis-chapter 36, which mentions the descendants of Esau, What was so special about each of them? What was their merit that they are mentioned in the Torah? Or what was the lesson we can learn from them?

Not only this lineage, my question is regarding the all lineages that were given in the Torah, because the Oral Torah gives us an explanation only for some of them.